# Is there a Winforms textbox event that can fire any time a textbox is ACCESSED and not necessarily CHANGED?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a Winforms app where a particular textbox field ("Phone Number") gets updated entirely programmatically, as the result of a user search on another form or as queries to a database for the overall main form's (saved) data.

We'd like the textbox to display with a red background whenever the data fits certain situations (blank is one of them, but there's also another string that can show up that we need to treat as "blank"). So I rigged this up on a TextChanged event handler.

However, sometimes the user will press a "Clear" button to blank out the Person data/fields on this form, including this Phone Number textbox.  And in that case, we don't want a blank to show up red. So I adjusted the TextChanged event handler to account for this. OK, so far, so good.

Yet if they have done a Clear and now another search takes place, dumping its results back into the field, if the updated data is empty string or null... well... the TextChanged event won't fire because the VALUE is not changing. It already was Null/Empty.  Yet in this situation, we'd WANT what I've got in the TextChanged event handler to fire.

I can't use the Validating Event Handler, because that only engages when a USER provides the input (I think?)

So far, my work-around has been to FORCE the event handler to fire after we're basically updating that field at the end of a search (possibly updating Null/Empty with Null/Empty).  And this works.  But it seems like there ought to be a better way. ??

I didn't see another event handler on that control that seemed to do what I'm looking for, but I thought I'd ask the crowd.

Thanks!

Comment: Detect when the user enters or leaves the field. Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.leave?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: From your code, don't ever set `.Text` directly.  Instead, create a method that receives the string to set.  In that method you can set your "clear flag" to false, then set the `.Text` property.  The only place you touch `.Text` directly would be inside that method, after clearing the flag.

Comment: So, is the TextBox bound to a datasource? When the data is updated/changed or the CurrencyManager sets the `Current` object, the Binding object set through the DataBindings property raises the `Format` (and then `Parse`) events.

Comment: You are talking about your code and work-around, but you forgot to show those. See [mcve].

Comment: At a highlevel it sounds straight foreward but without code... We can't guess how it all fits together.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you want a special kind of TextBox, one that fires the event whenever property Text is set, even if this doesn't lead to a change.

*A special kind of TextBox*?
Sounds like a derived class:

```
class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public override string Text 
    {
        get => base.Text;
        set
        {
            // if no change, only call OnTextChanged, otherwise call base.Text
            if (this.Text.Equals(value))
            {
                 base.OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            else
            {
                 base.Text = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If desired, use a stringComparer, like OrdinalIgnoreCase.

```
public IEqualityComparer<string> TextComparer {get; set;} = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

public override string Text 
{
    get => base.Text;
    set
    {
        if (this.TextComparer.Equals(this.Text, value))
        ...
```

The disadvantage of method is that `base.Text = value` will check for equality again. If you don't wan't this, look at the [source code of TextBox](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/TextBox.cs,7b5be95f7a8f33a8)

```
public string Text
{
    get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}
```

If you click on SetValue, you will jump deep inside windows. I'm not sure if you ever want to get there, given the fact that you won't update the Text property several times per second.